# If $A$ and $B$ are sets, do $\mathcal{P}(A - B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$ equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question**:

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, do $\mathcal{P}(A - B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$ equal?

---

**My Attempt**:

My instinct tells me that $\mathcal{P}(A - B) \neq \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$ always holds.

So I made some examples to help myself think.

(1) If $A = B \neq \varnothing$, then $A - B = \varnothing$, hence $\mathcal{P}(A - B) = \mathcal{P}(\varnothing) = \{ \varnothing \}$. Meanwhile, $\mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(A) = \varnothing$. Obviously, $\varnothing \neq \{ \varnothing \}$.

(2) If $A \neq \varnothing$ but $B = \varnothing$, then $A - B = A$, $\mathcal{P}(A - B) = \mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \varnothing,\, A,\, \ldots{} \}$, while $\mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(\varnothing) = \{ \varnothing,\, A,\, \ldots{} \} - \{ \varnothing \} = \{ A,\, \ldots{} \}$.

I don't know what to do next. Please help me proceed. Thx in advance. :)

Comment: Something hidden in plain sight: Which of $P(A-B)$ and $P(A)-P(B)$ is $\varnothing$ an element of?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(A-B)$?

Comment: So, $\varnothing \in \mathcal{P}(A-B)$ and $\varnothing \notin \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$ always holds, i.e. $\mathcal{P}(A-B) \neq \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$ always holds.

Comment: Don't forget that you can always give a counterexample to a false general statement...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you have everything you need to finish the problem, but I want to make it more clear:

$P(A-B)$ represents the set of all subsets of $A-B$ which implies that $\emptyset \in P(A-B)$ for all sets $A,B$.

But $P(A)-P(B) = \{\emptyset,...,A,...\}-\{\emptyset,...,B,...\} \implies \emptyset \notin P(A)-P(B).$

Therefore $P(A-B) \neq P(A)-P(B)$ for all sets $A,B$.

Comment: With all do respect Professor Santos, myself as well as the original poster and much of the world uses $-$ instead of \ for set difference. I think it looks better anyways!